# Goldengate Manager stopping with ACCESSRULE error

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

After a server reboot the Goldengate manager not starting. It starts up for few seconds then will go down with OGG-01877 missing explicit Accessrule for server collector. it was working from past 1 year without any issues.  Many time started and stopped and rebooted the server.

Linux 6.6 RHEL and goldengate 12.2.0.1 version.  oracle is 12.1.0.1

per google search added the ACCESSRULE, PROG*, ALLOW and did not help that either.

Is it possible to delete the manager and recreate the manager?  I would like to know if I can delete the manager without deleting the ext, pump and replicat?

Thanks.

Comment: OGG-01877 is a warning message only and should not cause Manager to terminate.  Can you post the content from your MGR.rpt file that comes after the OGG-01877 message?

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies that your manager is integrated with the Oracle clusterware. If your manager is integrated with the Oracle clusterware you can delete and recreate the manager without impacting the replication.

Typically GoldenGate managers fail to start due to port conflict. Check to see if there is a any port conflict in GOLDENGATE_HOME/ggserr.log. You will port in use message in this log. Issue netstat -an | grep [ port number value here ] to verify. You can find your GoldenGate port number in the mgr.prm file in GOLDENGATE_HOME/dirprm.